# Find the number of elements in the union of three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that there are 100 elements in A1, 1000 in A2, and 10, 000 in A3, find the number of elements in A1 ∪ A2 ∪ A3 in each of the cases below.

(a) A1 ⊆ A2 and A2 ⊆ A3

(b) the sets are pairwise disjoint

Draw and use relevant diagrams in each case.

First off, i'm not sure what that sideways union sign means? Also not sure how to do the question.

Thanks!

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ means that $A$ is a *subset* of $B$, that is: all elements of $A$ are elements of $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) As commented by drhab, we essentailly need to count only elements in $A3$ because $A1$ and $A2$ are included inside so it is just $10000$.

(b) The sets disjoint means you need to count all of them and add them up which means it is 11100.

Answer (score 0):

"Sideways unions signs" means "included in" or, equivalently, "is a subset of"

(a) With the definition of $\subset$, the answer to (a) is now clear: since $A_{1}\subset A_{3}$ et $A_{2}\subset A_{3}$, it follows directly that $A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}=A_{3}$, so that there are $|A_{3}|=10.000$ elements in the union.

(b) If the sets are pairwise disjoint, it is quite clear that the number of elements in the union is equal to the sum of the number of elements of each set.

It can be interesting to understand why the following relation is true (draw diagrams to develop the intuition):

$$|A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}|=|A_{1}|+|A_{2}|+|A_{3}|-|A_{1}\cap A_{2}|-|A_{1}\cap A_{3}|-|A_{2}\cap A_{3}| + |A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A{3}| $$

Comment: Ah i see, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!